# Android layout warning: This tag and its children can be replaced by one <TextView/> and a compound drawable

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

On my XML File, I get this notification:

```
This tag and its children can be replaced by one <TextView/> and a compound drawable
```

My xml code is like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/pharmacyBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/round"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:padding="14sp"
        android:src="@drawable/medical14" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#054126"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="@string/pharmacyBtn" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And i have a round xml:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#00FFFFFF"/>
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#c7d23e" />

    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="24dip"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="24dip"  
        android:topRightRadius="24dip"
        android:topLeftRadius="24dip"/>

</shape>
```

Now my graphical layout look like this:
[image]

I read some suggestions about how to join ImageView and TextView, android:drawableTop="@drawable/medical14", but when i join them in TextView, the graphical layout not seems like i want.

My new xml:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#054126"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="@drawable/round"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/medical14"
        android:text="@string/pharmacyBtn" />
```

My new graphical layout:

[image]

Comment: what is the result if you add android:drawablePadding="14dp" to the TextView?

Comment: the space between icon and text increase, but circle contains icon and textview, the circle grows taller

Comment: then probably you should simply ignore the warning

Comment: You could try adding a [`<padding/>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#padding-element) element to your shape drawable to see if you can get it right. Otherwise, just ignore the warning.